# Junit5 - Run test methods in parallel, with Test Instance per class, with ordering, with resource lock - last test executed first

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit5

I have 4 test cases

1. make a payment with credit card
2. make a payment with PayPal
3. refund a credit card transaction
4. refund a PayPal transaction

There are also a couple of constraints:

**a.** Obviously refund test cases need a payment to refund, which will be created by tests 1 and 2

**b.** Refund test cases involve async interactions, therefore they do a bunch of waiting and thus are slow - therefore it's better to have them run in parallel

For constraint a:

- I mark the test class with `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` - it lets me save payment IDs for refund in a class field.
- I mark the test class with `@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)` and assign order to test methods: `@Order(1)` to tests 1 and 2, `@Order(2)` to tests 3 and 4
- To make sure that tests 3 and 4 *don't start* until 1 and 2 are finished, I assign a `@ResourceLock("card")` to tests 1 and 3, `@ResourceLock("payPal")` to tests 2 and 4.

For constraint b, I mark the test class with `@Execution(value = ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)`.

Here's the code.

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@Execution(value = ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
class DemoTest {

    String txCard;
    String txPayPal;

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    @ResourceLock("card")
    void payCard() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        txCard = "foo";
    }

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    @ResourceLock("paypal")
    void payPayPal() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        txPayPal = "bar";
    }

    @Test
    @Order(2)
    @ResourceLock("card")
    void refundCard() throws InterruptedException {
        assert txCard != null;
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    @Test
    @Order(2)
    @ResourceLock("paypal")
    void refundPayPal() throws InterruptedException {
        assert txPayPal != null;
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void logStart(TestInfo testInfo) {
        System.out.printf("%s %s start %n", LocalTime.now(), testInfo.getTestMethod().get().getName());
    }

    @AfterEach
    void logEnd(TestInfo testInfo) {
        System.out.printf("%s %s ended %n", LocalTime.now(), testInfo.getTestMethod().get().getName());
    }

}
```

However, with this setup test refundPayPal() starts first - before payPayPal has finished.

```
10:17:34.769952200 payCard start 
10:17:34.769952200 refundPayPal start 
10:17:34.784918 refundPayPal ended 
10:17:34.994989800 payPayPal start 
10:17:35.785197300 payCard ended 
10:17:35.810474500 refundCard start 
10:17:36.003047800 payPayPal ended
```

I have found a workaround to this situation: if I add another dummy test with `@Order(3)`, it starts first, and my actual tests perform in expected order:

```
@Test
@Order(3)
void dummyTest() {
}
```

Result:

```
10:29:36.429508600 payCard start 
10:29:36.430479400 dummyTest start 
10:29:36.430479400 payPayPal start 
10:29:36.461309100 dummyTest ended 
10:29:37.460077 payPayPal ended 
10:29:37.485312200 refundPayPal start 
10:29:37.490314500 payCard ended 
10:29:37.585617100 refundCard start 
10:29:42.491899500 refundPayPal ended 
10:29:42.589084 refundCard ended
```

Any advice how can I make this work without this dummy test?

Comment: The elegant solution would be to ensure your tests don't depend on each other. So to test a refund, you create a new transaction that is then refunded in the same test method.

Comment: Slightly less elegant, would be to put the PayPal and Creditcard tests in their own class and run those test methods in sequence.

Comment: I also suspect the `@Order` annotation is ignored because `ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT` is used. It just happens to work in the right order by chance (JUnit orders test methods in a non-predictable deterministic manner). You could create a bug report for that.